# Solve $2\csc^2 x - \csc x - 1 = 0$ for $0 ≤ x ≤ 2π$

Tags: trigonometry

Solving some trigonometric equations and I'm getting a little thrown off by this one as it's the first one I've seen with the secondary trig ratios used instead of the primary ones. Could use a little help with this one please and thanks.

Comment: Well, if this was instead, say, ${2\sin^2(x) - \sin(x) - 1}$ (so you have ${\sin(x)}$ instead of ${\csc(x)}$), how would you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Try to not let the choice of function throw you; the approach is the same.  This is a quadratic equation.  Make the substitution to make this look more familiar.

Let $u = \csc x$

$2u^2 -  u - 1 = 0$
Factor
$(2u+1)(u-1) = 0$
$u = 1, u = -\frac 12$

Now we can think about these trig functions.

$|\csc x| \ge 1$ so we can disregard one of our values of $u.$

$\csc x = 1\\
\sin x = 1\\
x = \frac {\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

If $s = 1/\sin x $ the reciprocal trig relation can be

$$\dfrac{2}{x^2}-\dfrac{1}{x}-1=0,\to 2s^2-s-1 =0, \;(s-1)((2s+1)=0; $$

First root is $ 1/x=\pi/2 + 2 k \pi$

Second root is $ 1/x=3 \pi/2 \pm \pi/3 + 2 m \pi$

where $(k,m)$ are integers and we take their reciprocals once again.